# How can we use the command 'top‘ to monitor the total CPU usage and each processor usage simultaneously?

Tags: linux, cpu, top

You know that we can use the command `top` to monitor the real-time CPU usage and toggle the result display to the per-processor view by pressing key `1`. The disadvantage of it is you can only monitor either the whole CPU usage or each processor usage. That is, you can't see them simultaneously. Does anyone know this?

I know that we can use alternative commands such as `mpstat` or `sar` to do the job. But unfortunately, neither of them is available on our system and no chance can we install them.

Answer (score 4):

[htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) can. But you need setup it at first run for that purpose. For that hit F2 -> and addto left column CPU average bar and all cpus bar.

Answer (score 3):

You can run two terminals side-by-side.  Or, if that isn't an option, run `screen` to split a single terminal.